# When to fetch data from google developer api in app purchase

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have my WebAPI which manages In-App purchases.

For checking expired, refunded, canceled, and charged-back purchases I planned **daily fetch** from Google Developer API.

But I am afraid this will give users resources even when they have canceled it (at least for 1 day).

So I am planning best strategy to do this task.

So should I go ahead with this strategy or somebody has better.

(This is a very obvious question and can help others as well)

Comment: Downvoter is requested for the explanation because I think this is a very useful question.